# why it is always showing file is not found

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException  {
    String filename = "C:\\audiofile.wav";
    InputStream in = null;
    try{
       in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
         System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    AudioStream s = null;
    s = new AudioStream(in);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(s);
}
```

i have written this code in netbeans. Name of my audio file is audiofile.wav. But it is all time showing the exception "file not found". Can anyone help me ???

Comment: Is the file present in the `C:` drive?!

Comment: I guess the file is not there

Comment: Could you try `C:/audiofile.wav` instead? Just throwing out a bone here though.

Comment: yes the file is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first, you should paste your exception code!
then, I think java I/O support the both two way:

> "C:/audiofile.wav"
>   "C:\audiofile.wav"

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    String fileLocation = "C:\\1.diff";
    String fileLocation1 = "C:/1.diff";
    try {
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("11111111111111111111111111");

        while (line != null) {
            // Process line
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);

        }
        System.out.println("11111111111111111111111111");


    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream ff = new FileInputStream(fileLocation1);
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ff));
        String line1 = reader1.readLine();
        System.out.println("2222222222222222222222222");

        while (line1 != null) {
            // Process line
            line1 = reader1.readLine();
            System.out.println(line1);

        }
        System.out.println("2222222222222222222222222");

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

}

it works. I don't know what you did, anyway paste your error msg!

====

````
```
    private static void B() {
        String filename = "C:\\test.wav";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        try {
            AudioStream s = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(s);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

```
````

it works!

Comment: File not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(AudioStream.java:65)
 at media_player.Media_player.main(Media_player.java:31)
Java Result: 1                                                                    this is the error message.

Comment: do you sure you msg comes from here:   ``` catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
         System.out.println("File not found");```
    }

Comment: I think you just put a invalid wav file at the location, I downloaded a wav file, and I ran your code, it is right! finally, I think you made a mistake that you read file successfully, but you read it as an audio, it crushed!

Comment: please give your code a real wav file, then execute that code, you will get result!

Comment: Nice, well done! I think when you got problem, you should read error output carefully firstly, actually it will tell you the real reason. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

root folders in `C` drive of Windows Vista and above are protected by UAC. This requires you to run the java executable in Administrative mode.

However, you can shift the wav file elsewhere, where UAC will not interfere(like `Documents` folder of your currently logged in user) or the root of a different drive(Eg. D:\ and E:)

Also, make sure that the `audiofile.wav` is indeed in the said location(`C:\audiofile.wav`)

Answer (score 0):

Try just placing your file in a different location and see what happens

```
ProjectRootDir
          audiofile.wav
          src
```

And running this String

```
String filename = "audiofile.wav";
```